# Extention works in debug and release mod but incorrect after install?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions

I used to my old extention for VS 2017 and for now I'm gonna use it in VS 2019. Extension builds and works properly in VS 2019 and after changing manifest file It would seem installed correctly but... it's not :(
Toolbar button handler doesn't react; like there're buttons only and nothing more(despite it works when you build it in VS2019)

Comment: Hi Alexander, what do you mean it works when building it in VS2019? Do you mean F5 and start the experience instance?

Comment: Yes, I mean that

Answer (score 1):

As it turned out my extension is using synchronous autoload and VS 2019 doesn't allow it by default settings, so I found an answer here:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/updates-to-synchronous-autoload-of-extensions-in-visual-studio-2019/
Maybe this stupid question helps anyone else but I spent much time looking for the answer